# Where can I find studies on UX/UI Design for apps and websites?

Tags: usability-study, case-studies

When I google, I only get results about "user research methods" and these kind of things. What I really want is studies/stats about things like the best position for a navigation menu, best types of menus, color theory... you see? Where can I find those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.nngroup.com/   is the site you are looking for.

Comment: One of the best sites around when it comes to UX

Comment: nngroup is a gold standard when it comes to user experience related studies and articles

Answer (score 2):

https://www.interaction-design.org/ is also one of the best sites if you are looking to do online courses related to user experience.